# Fluent NHibernate mapping via middle table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a scenario that requires a mapping that needs to be done with joins to 2 tables via a middle table (see example) currently it is achieved via a formula which translates to a subquery, but i would like to use joins to do this more efficiently. please help

```
  Map(x => x.PropertyX).Formula(@"
               (SELECT C.ColumnX
                FROM   TableA A 
                       JOIN TableB B
                         ON A.Id = B.Id 
                       JOIN TableC C
                         ON C.Id = B.Id 
                WHERE  A.ColumnY = 898)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution you've used could be convertied into standard ORM use case. The native or object/entity oriented solution here would be to introduce `many-to-one` and `one-to-many` mappings. That would bring lot of benefits *(lazy loading == only if needed, querying...)*

*Small note, I am expecting that the FORMULA snippet in the question is just an example, because A.Id = B.Id = C.Id would mean B is not needed...*

So we should introduce entities:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public virtual IList<A> As { get; set; }  // not needed
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }  // not needed
    public virtual string ColumnY { get; set; }
}
```

and their mapping:

```
public AMap()
{
    References(x => x.B);
}
public BMap()
{
    References(x => x.C);
    HasMany(x => x.As);   // not needed
}
public CMap()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Bs);   // not needed
    Map(x => x.ColumnY);
}
```

Now we can get the same result with standard query with few JOINs.

In case, that the

- we would like to reduce that chain and
- we **know** that the FORMULA content is always **readonly**...

we can create a virtual entity - mapped to a view:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual BView BView { get; set; }
}
public class BView
{
    public virtual string ColumnY { get; set; }
}

public AMap()
{
    References(x => x.BView)
}
public BMap()
{
    Table("viewName");
}
```

Where `viewName` would represent a view on a DB side. In case, we cannot introduce view, we can define it as an inlined SELECT

```
public BMap()
{
    Subselect(@"
        SELECT B.col1 as COL1,
               C.col2 as COL2,
               ..
        FROM B
         LEFT JOIN C
          ON B.CId = C.Id
        ");
}
```

Comment: A.Id and C.Id are not the same. your assumption is correct